# Easy way to remove columns in numpy array that add up to zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there an easy way to remove columns that add up to zero and their corresponding rows in a numpy matrix?

I am trying to create a transition matrix for PageRank but the code I wrote seems not to be the most efficient.

```
i = 1
while True:
    if len(graph) == i-1:
        break
    else:
        col_sum = np.sum(graph[:,i-1])
        if col_sum == 0:
            graph = np.delete(graph, np.s_[i-1], 1)
            graph = np.delete(graph, i-1, 0)
            nodes.remove(nodes[i-1])
            i = 0
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vectorized version using `np.ix_`

```
mask = np.nonzero(np.sum(graph, axis = 1))[0]
graph = graph[np.ix_(mask, mask)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is designed to do just that kind of thing without loops. Most operators like `np.sum` are designed to work with matrices or multi-dimensional arrays and take an `axis` argument telling it along which dimension to operate. Finally, we can use index or boolean masking arrays to select elements from an array.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

nodes = [chr(i + 65) for i in range(10)]

a = (np.random.randn(10, 10) > 1.5).astype(int)
print('before:')
print(a)
print(nodes)

col_sum = np.sum(a, axis=0)  # sum of each column columns
idx = np.flatnonzero(col_sum)  # indices of non-zero columns

# remove columns and rows
a = a[:, idx][idx, :]  # note that a[idx, idx] won't work

# if nodes was an array we could do this:
#nodes = nodes[idx]

# but nodes is a list, so we need a list comprehension:
nodes = [n for n, i in zip(nodes, idx) if i]

print('\nafter:')
print(a)
print(nodes)
```

Result:

```
before:
[[0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']

after:
[[0 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
['A', 'B', 'C']
```